# Regular expression to validate time until 04:00

Tags: regex

Hello I have this `^([02][0-4])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}$` expression for checking time in a form.
My problem is that the maximum that I can input should be 04:00 and not 04:59
but of course including all the other numbers like 02:47 or 03:59.

I never used regex, that's the best I could do can someone help me or at least explain me?

Any help apprecciated, thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could use an alternation to include `04:00` as an edge case:

```
^(0[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]|04:00)$
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you want to exclude `00:00` proper from being included, then we have to do more work, but we can try using:

```
^(00:0[1-9]|00:[1-5][0-9]|0[1-3]:[0-5][0-9]|04:00)$
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the second regex pattern:

```
^(                     from the start of the string
    00:0[1-9]          match 00:01 - 00:09
    |                  or
    00:[1-5][0-9]      match 00:10 - 00:59
    |                  or
    0[1-3]:[0-5][0-9]  match 01:00 - 03:59
    |                  or
    04:00              match 04:00
)$
```

Comment: Just what I was about to say

Comment: How can I except 00:00?

Comment: @FatRat Check my updated answer for a way to do this.  You need a much uglier regex, but it is possible.

Comment: I don't know the language but a negative lookahead might also work `^(?!00:00)(0[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]|04:00)$` +1

Comment: Regarding the explanation of your second pattern, you can include comments into a regex with the syntax `(?#your comment goes here...)`.